# How to decide the range for the hyperparameter space in SVM tuning? (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, deep-learning, svm, hyperparameters

I am tuning an SVM using a for loop to search in the range of hyperparameter's space. The `svm` model learned contains the following fields

```
   SVMModel: [1×1 ClassificationSVM]
          C: 2
FeaturesIdx: [4 6 8]
      Score: 0.0142
```

Question1) What is the meaning of the field 'score' and its utility?

Question2) I am tuning the `BoxConstraint`, C value. Let, the number of features be denoted by the variable `featsize`. The variable `gridC` will contain the search space which can start from any value say 2^-5, 2^-3, to 2^15 etc. So, `gridC = 2.^(-5:2:15)`. I cannot understand if there is a way to select the range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** `score` had been documented in [here](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/stats/compactclassificationsvm.predict.html?searchHighlight=predict&s_tid=doc_srchtitle#d119e588869), which says:

> Classification Score
>   The SVM classification score for classifying observation x is the signed distance from x to the decision boundary ranging from -∞ to +∞.
>   A positive score for a class indicates that x is predicted to be in
>   that class. A negative score indicates otherwise.

**In two class cases**, if there are six observations, and the predict function gave us some score value called `TestScore`, then we could determine which class does the specific observation ascribed by:

```
TestScore=[-0.4497    0.4497
           -0.2602    0.2602;
           -0.0746    0.0746;
            0.1070   -0.1070;
            0.2841   -0.2841;
            0.4566   -0.4566;];
[~,Classes] = max(TestScore,[],2);
```

In the two-class classification, we can also use `find(TestScore > 0)` instead, and it is clear that the first three observations are belonging to the second class, and the 4th to 6th observations are belonging to the first class.

**In multiclass cases**, there could be several scores > 0, but the code `max(scores,[],2)` is still validate. For example, we could use the code (from [here](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/stats/fitcsvm.html?searchHighlight=fitcsvm&s_tid=doc_srchtitle#bt9w6j6-4), an example called Find Multiple Class Boundaries Using Binary SVM) following to determine the classes of the predict `Samples`.

```
for j = 1:numel(classes);
    [~,score] = predict(SVMModels{j},Samples);
    Scores(:,j) = score(:,2); % Second column contains positive-class scores
end
[~,maxScore] = max(Scores,[],2);
```

Then the `maxScore` will denote the predicted classes of each sample.

**2.** The `BoxConstraint` denotes `C` in the SVM model, so we can train SVMs in different hyperparameters and select the best one by something like:

```
gridC = 2.^(-5:2:15);
for ii=1:length(gridC)
SVModel = fitcsvm(data3,theclass,'KernelFunction','rbf',...
    'BoxConstraint',gridC(ii),'ClassNames',[-1,1]);
%if (%some constraints were meet) 
%  %save the current SVModel
%end
end
```

Note: Another way to implement this is using [libsvm](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/), a fast and easy-to-use SVM toolbox, which has the interface of MATLAB.

Comment: thank you for such an easier explanation. However, I have few comments on two things . Could you please clarify these 2 points? (1) It seems that score is a matrix of values, where the number of columns is equal to the number of features and the number of rows are the number of examples. But in the code, `score` is a scalar value. How does Matlab give  a scalar value is unclear.

Comment: (2) in research papers do we report the classification result using the tuned learner on the unseen data? What I mean is that after calculations in point 2 are done, we get a final learned model. We run the entire training+cross-validation set on this learned model. This set is the same as that used in the kfold cross-validation. After that, we predict on a test set which should ideally be the one that was never used in the learning procedure.

Comment: (1)Note that the number of columns of the matrix score equal to the number of classes, not the features. So if the score is a scalar value, your MATLAB has done an "one-class learning". (2) In the most paper, we don't use the "score" to predict unknown observations, the accuracy of the classification by the model of the CV set is more convincing. @SrishtiM